# How can I run a python script on an EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I've ssh'd into my EC2 instance and have the python script and .txt files I'm using on my local system.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to transfer the .py and .txt files to my instance and then run them there?  I've not even been able to install python on the instance yet

Comment: Can someone that's more knowledgable than me when it comes to SO explain why I've been downvoted by the first person that viewed this?  It seems legitimate to me (obviously) so I'd like to understand what the issue is

Comment: Hi Bahrom, I've already looked through every result on the first page of Google and the referenced previous question, but nothing explains specifically how to upload and run python scripts.  A link to AMI's or importing VMs doesn't provide a solution to my question

Comment: This can also be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2Wc8JIS-p8

Comment: Sure I watched that video about half an hour ago, and it explained very well how to ssh into my instance (which I've now done) but not how to run a script after that.  I'm not in my instance, just with no idea how to transfer my files to the instance or run them

Comment: I appreciate your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

If your EC2 instance is running a linux OS, you can use the following command to install python:

sudo apt-get install python*.*

Where the * represents the version you want to install, such as 2.7 or 3.4. Then use the python command with the first argument as the location of the python file to run it.

Comment: I'll second what Matthew said.  If it's RedHat, Fedora, the Amazon Linux AMI, or any instance with `yum` as the package manager, you can do 
      `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" `